# Can connect to VPN server with local but not with public IP - port forwarding issue?

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding, openvpn

I am trying to set up an OpenVPN server. I mostly followed [this tutorial](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html).

Problem: When the client tries connects, it fails with

> Sun Jun 10 20:32:26 2018 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET][server's public IP]:1194
>
> Sun Jun 10 20:32:26 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1528655546,WAIT,,,

As I suspected that port forwarding might be the issue, I changed to client's config file from

```
remote [server's public IP] 1194
```

to

```
remote [server's private IP] 1194
```

After this change, the client connects successfully. From this, I conclude that the problem is in fact port forwarding and not related to the general VPN configuration. Therefore, here's how my local network is set up:

- I have a cable modem that is connected to the internet (Compal CH7466CE).
- A FRITZ!Box (7360SL) is connected to the modem with a LAN cable. It serves as a WiFi access point for my laptops (one of which runs the VPN server).

I set up two forwarding rules:

- In the modem: Forward UDP 1194 to FRITZ!Box's MAC address.
- In the FRITZ!Box: Forward UDP 1194 to the VPN server's MAC address.

I also tried to tell the modem to forward to the VPN server directly, but this didn't work either. (Probably because the server and the modem are on different networks, separated by the FRITZ!Box – right?)

Here I am stuck. How can I fix or troubleshoot this? How to find out where the forwarding fails?

---

UPDATE: Even if I'm outside of my local network, I cannot connect:

```
Mon Jun 11 09:14:10 2018 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mon Jun 11 09:14:10 2018 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]95.216.17.186:1194
Mon Jun 11 09:14:10 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1528701250,WAIT,,,
Mon Jun 11 09:15:10 2018 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Mon Jun 11 09:15:10 2018 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Mon Jun 11 09:15:10 2018 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Mon Jun 11 09:15:10 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1528701310,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,
Mon Jun 11 09:15:10 2018 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Mon Jun 11 09:15:12 2018 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Mon Jun 11 09:15:12 2018 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mon Jun 11 09:15:12 2018 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]95.216.17.186:1194
Mon Jun 11 09:15:12 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1528701312,WAIT,,,
Mon Jun 11 09:16:12 2018 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Mon Jun 11 09:16:12 2018 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Mon Jun 11 09:16:12 2018 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Mon Jun 11 09:16:12 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1528701372,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,
Mon Jun 11 09:16:12 2018 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Mon Jun 11 09:16:14 2018 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Mon Jun 11 09:16:14 2018 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mon Jun 11 09:16:14 2018 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]95.216.17.186:1194
Mon Jun 11 09:16:14 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1528701374,WAIT,,,
Mon Jun 11 09:17:14 2018 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Mon Jun 11 09:17:14 2018 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Mon Jun 11 09:17:14 2018 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Mon Jun 11 09:17:14 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1528701434,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,
```

Comment: You need to be outside of your own network to test this, because the Fritzbox does not understand loopback traffic. It sends the traffic out to the internet, and discards it when it comes back.

Comment: Accessing the web server public IP from your private network will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: Thank you both, I was not aware of this. I'll test from outside of my network tomorrow.